# Generate PDF in Play Framework Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, pdf-generation, playframework-2.2

I'm using Play framework 2.2.x and I'm looking for some plugin/lib for generating PDF.

I found this plugin:
https://github.com/joergviola/play20-pdf, 
but it's for Java and is not supported already

Do u know some repository with this library? Or some alternatives for Scala and Play Framework?

=== Update

I found some fork, but still no working repository
https://github.com/alias1/play2pdf

Comment: You can have a look at http://play-demo.applidok.com/

Answer (score 2):

Try this one https://github.com/Kaliber/scala-pdf. It is really easy to use, and you can define your own css or even use bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a very good solution : https://github.com/cloudify/sPDF

Otherwise, I highly recommend http://www.html2pdf.it/

Comment: Very nice Scala integration. It relies on http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ which renders HTML using Webkit, so it may not be a portable solution depending on your deployment constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Well  javascript  can be easy solution . You can use jspdf .